# PgHero Gem is not working in Rails Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I have added PgHero Gem and trying to deploy code but deployment got failed.

However, i have directly installed PgHero gem on my server by using this command "RAILS_ENV=production gem install pghero", Gem is installed but as i'm added this line into  config/routs.rb, and restart puma, it shows 404 error and my application is not in running form.

After adding gem, i have precompiled my assets but no luck. plus i used Ubuntu commands to install pghero but facing same issue.

It gives this error: "uninitialized constant PgHero (NameError)"

I just want to add PgHero gem in my server.

Gem Link: [PgHero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero/blob/master/guides/Rails.md)

Comment: The correct way to add a gem dependency is to add it to the Gemfile and then `bundle install`. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you see an error like `uninitialized constant PgHero (NameError)` is due to the lib not being loaded, so you may want to take a look at some hints:

- Are you running with the same environment group the gem was defined?
- If you set `required: false` in your Gemfile, then you need to add `require 'lib` into your Ruby file
- Ensure you're running your commands prefixed with `bundle exec` so to have the gems loaded at runtime.